# Extract, modify and reload S Parameters in Matlab (RF Toolbox)

Tags: matlab

I need to modify a touchstone file containing 20 ports (so *.s20p) by editing the S-parameters of 3 ports using datas from a txt file: in practice I need to merge 2 S-parameters.

I saw in the RF Toolbox that I can extract the `Sij` with command `rfparam`
so I can do this:

```
S = sparameters('S_Matrix.s20p');
S_new = sparameters('S_Matrix_new.s3p');

S11_new = rfparam(S_new,1,1);
```

At this point, how replace the S11 inside S with S11_new?
I need this, because S_new has some more information than S only for the 3 ports that I need to merge inside